# $\left|\frac{1}{A^2 B} - \frac{1}{C^2D} \right| \leq |A-C| \times constant $

Tags: inequality

Could you help me please, to make a majoration of this type :

$$\left|\frac{1}{A^2 B} - \frac{1}{C^2D} \right| \leq |A-C| \times constant $$

My only hypothesis is :

$$A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{ z = \rho e^{\theta}\in\mathbb{C} \text{ such that } \rho > \eta \}$$

for $\eta > 0$.

Thank you for your help,

Nawak

Comment: Verify your hypothesis: Try $A=C$ and $B\not = D$.